# Cordova Http request Issue in Android Device

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, http, ionic-framework

I have Cordova > 4.0.0, so it has CSP and Whitelist security measures.

In the browser I can make the request to the API, but in an Android device it gives me this error:

> file:///http:/xxx.xxx.xxx/api/Login/DoLogin
>
> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

I searched for a solution, but nothing worked.

My config.xml has this fields (according to [Cordova Whitelist Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) documentation):

```
 <allow-navigation href="*" />
 <allow-intent href="*" />
 <access origin="*" />"
```

INFO: I tryed multiple combination's of this parameter's, with the URL of the Api.
(Ex: `<access origin="http://xxx.xxx.xxx/" subdomains="true"  />`)

In my Index.html I have this CSP:

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
 content="default-src *; style-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
               script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">
```

INFO: In here I have tried other combination's of CSP according to [Cordova Whitelist Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist)

So, before anyone ask I have installed:

- cordova-whitelist-plugin

And using Restangular for the requests.

I can't figure it out, can someone help me?

EDIT: Request Code

> var baseLogin = Restangular.all('http:/xxx.xxx.xxx/api/Login/DoLogin');
>
> ```
> dataApi.doLogin = function (var1, var2, var3, var4, var5) {
>     // $http() returns a $promise that we can add handlers with .then()
>     var parameter = null;
>         parameter = {
>             var1: var1,
>             var2: var2,
>             var3: var3,
>             var4: var4,
>             var5: var5
>         };
>     return baseLogin.post(parameter);
> };
> ```

I use Ionic, so it has CORS issues in browser, to resolve that I use a proxy in ionic.project file, but it's only called in the browser, in the device it is not using this.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Doesn't look like an content security policy related error. It rather seems your url is wrong: I guess it should look like http:/xxx.xxx.xxx/api/Login/DoLogin without the file:///

Comment: @Phonolog I was going to add exactly that. As the phone is acessing "remotely" the file there is not needed and causing an internal exception.

Comment: I don't know where the file:// is coming from, that is why. I will try with $resource or $http, to see if it changes anything

Comment: I'm not familiar with Restangular, so i can't really help to figure out what's wrong here, maybe it's even a bug in Restangular. For a quick fix i would suggest to do a simple post with $http, this worked fine on my android device...

Comment: @pcagica Did you manage to resolve this issue? I'm having exactly the same problem with Cordova and Restangular

Comment: It was some problem with restangular that was pretending file:// to the URL, I couldn't solve it, so I stopped using restangular. @zorza

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the "file" from your url, as @Phonolog commented out.

It's not necessary and it may be causing an internal exception on the phone.
Try to use just *http:/xxx.xxx.xxx/api/Login/DoLogin*, as you would with an WCF service. Also be sure that this endpoint is properly configured to accept incoming requests.

Addendun: Also, you should be careful with these tags:

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<access origin="*" />"
```

These means allowing access to everything, and also allows communications with others applications/services. So be careful, this can cause a security issue in the future.

Comment: I know what this mean, It's for debug purpose only, I was just trying to put it to work, and I can't even with access to everything 

I noticed the file:// but I don't make the request to that URL, something is changing my URL and prepend it with file://. And I don't know what. 

I'm using Restangular, to make the request.

Comment: I did not understand your comment, sorry. You don't mal? Did it not work? If it did not, what was the exception this time?

Comment: Sorry, it was sent unfinished.

Comment: Maybe adding some of the code where you do your api call might help to resolve this...

Comment: @pcagica it's okay, we're here to help. Add some more code as Phonolog requested, if you don't mind.

Comment: It's a simple request, but I will edit the question.